Programmatically sending one-time passcodes to external users
I need to periodically have groups of customers fill out a SharePoint form each year. The
questions on the form are presented using a form customization app (SPFx).
If the user does not already exist in my SharePoint group (FormMembers) I
want to add them programmatically (Typescript/React extension) and email
them a link that will allow them to access the form via one time passcode
that expires after 30 days.
If the user does already exist I want to just send the email with a new passcode
that will expire after 30 days.
Does anyone have any example code of such a solution or know where I might
find one?
Thanks
